# How do I create JSON objects in C# where the property names are set on the fly?

Tags: .net, json

I need to return an array of JSON objects that is the result of an SQL query. The SQL query can be anything so I need to create the property names as well as the values on the fly in code.

For example, "select first_name, last_name from employees" I want to return:

```
{ "data": 
   [{
        "first_name": "dave",
        "last_name": "thielen"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "john",
        "last_name": "smith"
    }]
}
```

But the next query could be "select item, price, tax, ship_date from orders and want to return:

```
{ "data": 
   [{
        "item": "HD TV",
        "price": "598.95"
        "tax": "59.89"
        "ship_date": "2013-08-26"
    },
    {
        "item": "Cables",
        "price": "54.67"
        "tax": "5.47"
        "ship_date": "2013-08-26"
    }]
}
```

How can I build this up in C# and then convert to JSON?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use anonymous types, For ex (using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)),

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new { 
        data = new[]{ 
            new{name="a",surname="b"},
            new{name="c",surname="d"},
        } 
    }
    );
```

would give

```
{"data":[{"name":"a","surname":"b"},{"name":"c","surname":"d"}]}
```

**EDIT**

> I need "a": "b"

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "a","b" }
        }
    );
```

output: `{"a":"b"}`

**EDIT2**

And a funny one

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "a","b" },
    { "c","d" }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        new { data = dict.Select(x => new[]{x}.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value)) }
    );
```

Output:  `{"data":[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]}`

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work. For your example I need "a": "b"

Comment: Please add to answer to create a List<Dictionary<string, object>> to get an array of on the fly named objects. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @DavidThielen I think everyone got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to look at [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

There are a couple other libraries out there but I think that is the most used. It has a simple serialize/deserialize API.

Comment: I looked at Json.NET but it does not appear to have a way to do this that I could find.