# Linq query to d3.js chart

Tags: c#, javascript, json, linq, d3.js

**I am looking for a good way to feed a [d3.js bubble chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) with data from my MVC application.** For example the standard bubble chart expects nested data in the form:

```
{
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "analytics",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "cluster",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "CNN",
                            "size": 3938
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "graph",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "MTV",
                            "size": 3534
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I have on the server side is this linq query to a SQL database:

```
var results = from a in db.Durations
                          where a.Category == "watch"
                          group a by a.Description
                              into g
                              select new
                              {
                                  name = g.Key,
                                  size = g.Select(d => new{d.Begin, d.End}).Sum(d => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("hh", d.Begin, d.End))
                              };

            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The query result, parsed as Json, looks like this:

```
[{"name":"CNN","size":1950},{"name":"MTV","size":1680}]
```

I've got stuck in the head on what would be a good way to achieve the correct formatting and to create the nested structure from my query results..

1. server-side, using [anonymous types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452765/how-do-i-create-json-objects-in-c-sharp-where-the-property-names-are-set-on-the)
2. server-side, adjusting the linq-query
3. client-side, using [d3.js nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-_nest)
4. use a simpler bubble model since for my purpose, the nested
   structure with children is not really needed
5. something totally different and much much cooler than 1-4

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your return statement with the following one.

```
return Json(new
    {
        name = "Sites",
        children = results
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

That will give you the following:

```
{
  "name": "Sites",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "CNN",
      "size": 1950
    },
    {
      "name": "MTV",
      "size": 1680
    }
  ]
}
```

To serve as an example, suppose each website had an additional `string Type` property, with values such as `"News"` or `"Music"`.  Then you could do the following.

```
return Json(new
    {
        name = "Sites",
        children = results.GroupBy(site => site.Type).Select(group => new
        {
            name = group.Key,
            children = group
        }
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This would give you something like the following.

```
{
  "name": "Sites",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "News",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "CNN",
          "size": 1950
        },
        {
          "name": "The Verge",
          "size": 1600
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Music",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "MTV",
          "size": 1680
        },
        {
          "name": "Pandora",
          "size": 2000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```